# CoverFlow Library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, coverflow

Any recommendations for libraries which allow me to implement coverflow on Windows PC applications?

Thanks!

Comment: Any framework in particular as I know of one for Qt apps.

Comment: Anything, as long as I can integrate it (without too much effort) into a Visual Studio environment

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's Qt specific but there is [Pictureflow](http://code.google.com/p/pictureflow/) which is also expanded in the [qxt](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/index.html) class [QxtFlowView](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxtflowview.html).

I've used qxt but you need to build it yourself which might put Qt beginners off.

If you're working with Qt then there is a free MSVC plugin that you can use.